# TinyMCE4 `image_list` external url

Tags: image, xmlhttprequest, tinymce, tinymce-4

I am trying to get TinyMCE 4's `image_list` to work with a URL returning JSON data as specified in the example [here](https://www.tiny.cloud/docs/plugins/image/#image_list).

I have setup a `GET` endpoint `http://demo.com/media` on my server which gives back a JSON response consisting of a list of objects with their `title` and `value` attributes set, for example:

`[{"title":"demo.jpg","value":"http://demo.com/demo.jpg"}]`

I have also specified the option `image_list: "http://demo.com/media"` when initializing the plugin.

However, when I click the image icon in the toolbar, nothing pops up. All I can see in the network tab is an `OPTIONS` request with status 200, but then nothing. The `GET` request I was expecting never happens.

[image]

What is the correct way of using `image_list` in TinyMCE 4? Also, does anyone have a working demo example? I couldn't find anything.

Answer (score 0):

It is somewhat hard to say what the issue is without seeing the exact data your URL is returning.  I have created a TinyMCE Fiddle to show (in general) how this is supposed to work:

http://fiddle.tinymce.com/pwgaab

There is a JavaScript variable at the top (`pretendFetchedData`) that simulates what you would grab from the server (an array of JavaScript objects) and that is referenced via `image_list`.

If you enter your URL (`http://demo.com/media`) into a browser window what is returned?  Are you sure its an array of JavaScript objects?

Comment: `[{"title":"demo.jpg","value":"http://demo.com/demo.jpg"}]` it is a JSON-encoded array of objects

Comment: I have also managed to make it work by hard-coding an array of objects in my JS, but the problem is, when I specify an URL, TinyMCE only makes an `OPTIONS` request and that's it. And as you know, an `OPTIONS` request has no body. So it should also follow up with a `GET` I think

Comment: If an `OPTIONS` request is sent but no `GET` then it sounds like you have a CORS issue.  If the data coming from a different domain?

Comment: Yes, but look at my response headers in the picture

Answer (score 0):

I have the identical problem.  No matter what I do with the detail of the format (e.g. putting quotes round title and value), nothing happens.

I guess the only way (for me anyway) is to insert the list into the script with php before sending the web page.